# Azure Data Factory SFTP connection with Authentication type SSH public key authentication

Tags: azure, sftp, factory

Our corporate SFTP server uses combination of Key and User password for authentication. I am able to connect to SFTP using MobaXtern using private key as one of the setting and popup asked for user password.
However, in ADF V2 SFTP linked service , I don't see any option to provide password ( I can see ony pass phrase option) . The error I got is "  No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (password,keyboard-interactive)"

Where do you think I can provide password ?

[error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMHMb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking something similar to what is asked here .

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/def80450-4b68-421b-81a6-b562cba6927c/data-factory-sftp-multifactor-authentication?forum=AzureDataFactory

At this time this scenario is not supported in ADF.